# Want to fetch exact record from table mysql laravel

Tags: mysql

Want to fetch records that are having exact match with My sql table

the table is looking like this

id question_id asset_id

1
59
2

2
58
2

3
57
2

5
57
3

6
56
2

7
56
3

so from this I want to fetch records which are having exact records like. asset_id = 2 (so for this question id are 58 and 59)

And while checking asset id = 2,3 the records should be 56 and 57 as question ids

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` function, but an answer above will have better perfomance

```
SELECT question_id FROM `questions`
GROUP BY question_id 
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(asset_id ORDER BY asset_id) = '2,3'
```

Comment: This is perfect answer

Comment: @RajendraBanker, ok, i am happy, but better add condition WHERE asset_id in (2, 3) to make it work faster

Answer (score 2):

You can count the number of distinct `asset_id` per `question_id` and only select rows where the count equals the number of values you are searching for and the count equals the number of values which are the ones you are searching for

```
SELECT question_id
FROM assets
GROUP BY question_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT asset_id) = 2 AND
       COUNT(asset_id) = SUM(asset_id IN (2, 3))
```

Output:

```
question_id
56
57
```

Or for a single value search:

```
SELECT question_id
FROM assets
GROUP BY question_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT asset_id) = 1 AND
       COUNT(asset_id) = SUM(asset_id = 2)
```

Output:

```
question_id
58
59
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eGRpidRRzod51sBVdgExoG/1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nick but this is not working while we changing condition like

SELECT question_id
FROM assets
WHERE asset_id = 2
GROUP BY question_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT asset_id) = 1

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eGRpidRRzod51sBVdgExoG/0

Comment: @RajendraBanker apologies, I misread your question. I've corrected the query.